# Cinemagraph Encoding in C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, animated-gif

How can we encode [cinemagraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinemagraph)? Also how to identify the area which usually moves in an cinemagraph? Is there any specification for cinemagraph? My end goal is to create a encoder in C++ which can take multiple frames and encode it as cinemagraph.

Comment: The number of question marks is a clear sign this question is too broad - this asks three different questions. On the other hand, the fact that they all are short questions shows a repeated lack of effort.

Comment: How is a `cinemagraph` different from an animated GIF? Do you have some examples of what you want to make?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specification and there is no algorithm that will define what moves and what is still. Cinemagraphs are an art form. It's the artist's choice that makes the difference between a simple animated gif or video and an appealing cinemagraph.

I think you did not fully understand what this is about so you will have difficulties to implement a software for creating cinemagraphs.

Any software that is able to blend images and export videos or animated gifs can be used to create cinemagraphs. So maybe start with these features.